# Would it be possible to create a “DIY Anaconda” by just installing all of its libraries to a venv?

Tags: python, anaconda

I’ll be using Anaconda for university and I dislike how bloated it feels having it on my system. From what I can tell, Anaconda is basically just Python prepackaged with a lot of libraries for data science. Would it be possible for me to just install all of the libraries to a venv? If so, where could I find a list of the libraries?

Sorry if I’m misunderstanding Anaconda by the way :)

Comment: i think most bloat might be qt which is very popular.  you can run `conda list` from your base anaconda prompt for the original list

Comment: Anaconda contains a number python dependencies which are not available from pip. So depending on what you are planing to do this might not always give you the same result as using conda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Miniconda is a minimal version of Anaconda where you can install packages as needed instead of having them all included by default.